# XLabs ExtendedLabel change fonts does not work in Xamarin.Forms for UWP app

Tags: fonts, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have [Xamarin forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) project and I want to use ExtendedLabel for use own custom fonts in PCL project. when I follow [ExtendedLabel instruction](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ExtendedLabel) every things is ok for Droid project but when I want to run UWP project **I see my fonts dose not apply for any label**. the interesting note is when I use Xamarin built-in label and set FontFamily property with `font name.ttf#friendly name` pattern every things is ok for UWP project but ExtendedLabel does not show correct fonts in UWP app.

Dose anyone have idea to resolve UWP project problem?

I am using:

```
Visual Studio 2015 update 3
Xamarin forms 2.3.0.107
XLabs forms 2.2.0-pre5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dose anyone have idea to resolve UWP project problem

Ref [this document](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ExtendedLabel)

For Android and iOS platform, we can use `FontName` property, but for Windows Phone platform, it uses **`FriendlyFontName`** property:

Quote:

> This property is only necessary for the Windows Phone platform. This
>   can be found on the first line of the font or in the font preview. If
>   not given then the file name excluding the extension is used. However
>   this cannot be guaranteed to work.

But seems like XLabs didn't handle the `FriendlyFontName` setting correctly. I just tried its [official sample for UWP](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/samples/XLabs.Samples/XLabs.Samples.UWP)

For the ExtendedLabel scenario, the font setting is incorrect.

After some investigations, based on this [issue](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/324), I found a workaround to fit Windows Phone and UWP scenario.

Setting `FontName` and using `OnePlatform` for WINRT scenario in xaml:

```
 <controls:ExtendedLabel FontName="Kristen ITC"
                                      FontSize="20"
                                      FriendlyFontName="Kristen ITC"
                                      HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                      Text="This uses 'FontName' = 'Kristen ITC' set in XAML and 'OnPlatform' properties, size 20">
                <controls:ExtendedLabel.FontFamily>
                  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                              iOS=""
                              Android=""
                              WinPhone="Kristen ITC"/>
                </controls:ExtendedLabel.FontFamily>              
</controls:ExtendedLabel>
```

**Please notice that the specific Font should be installed in your platform OS.**

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Check my [forked repository](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/samples/XLabs.Samples/XLabs.Samples/Pages/Controls/ExtendedLabelPage.xaml#L33)

Comment: many thanks, I hope to resolve this bug in next version of ExtendedLabel.